# fcgi_mod and phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mod-fcgid

I have setup Debian Lenny, Apache2, PHP 5.3.1 fcgi_mod, and MySQL and it works fine.

But PHPMyadmin doesn't work. When I go to : http://phpmyadmin.domain.com it downloads the index.php under PHPMyadmin instead of executing it.

I think I need to wrap the request in a fcgiwrapper like I did all the virtual hosts. But how do I do that? Apparently there are not that many tutorials on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried adding `Options ExecCGI` to the virtual host in the apache config?

Answer (score 0):

I know it is in german. But the basic idea is easys to get since the vhost configuration is the same: http://www.ulrich-block.de/?p=3